# Usage of boost multi_multi index

Tags: c++, boost, multi-index

my code(not written by me) use multi index container.

```
typedef boost::multi_index_container<
        Block*,
        boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
            boost::multi_index::random_access<>,
            boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(Block,uint,pages_invalid) >
      >
    > active_set;

typedef active_set::nth_index<0>::type ActiveBySeq;
typedef active_set::nth_index<1>::type ActiveByCost;
active_set active_cost;
```

"Block" is one of class.

This container is used as priority queue.

```
ActiveByCost::iterator it = active_cost.get<1>().end();
    --it;
```

I'd like to search a member which have variable A=="specific value".
(not for priority queue)

A is one of member variable of Class Block.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to search a member which have variable A=="specific value"

If there is no index on this member then that would require a linear search in the random-access index:

```
auto pos = std::find_if(active_cost.begin(), active_cost.end(), 
                        [](Block const* p) { return p->A == "specific value"; }
if(pos == active_cost.end())
    // Not found.
```

Comment: Does "If there is no index on this member " means that A is not array?

Comment: @WKK That means there is no index over that member in `boost::multi_index::indexed_by<>`.

Comment: @maxim_egorushkin Thank you. One more question, how can I access the data of multi_index container with position?

Comment: @WKK Like `active_cost[index]`. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/rnd_indices.html